# MSBuild AfterBuild event failing on my machine only - error MSB3073

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, msbuild, ilmerge

We've got an after build event that uses ILMerge to combine all project assemblies into a single one.  Up until recently, this all worked fine, and in fact does work fine on all the other development machines (and our build server).

The after build section in the `.csproj` file looks like:

```
   <Target Condition="$(NCrunch) != '1'" Name="AfterBuild">
    <CreateItem Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.dll' AND 
   $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::
   IsMatch(%(Filename),'CompanyName'))" 
    Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)">
    <Output ItemName="AssembliesToMerge" TaskParameter="Include"/>
    </CreateItem>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="============================"/>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="MERGING: @(AssembliesToMerge-&gt;'%(Filename)')"/>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="=================================="/>
    <ExecCommand="&quot;$(MSBuildProjectPath)..\..\..
    \Libraries\dependencies\ILMerge\Ilmerge.exe&quot; /internalize:&quot;
    $(MSBuildProjectPath)ILMerge-internalize-excludes.txt&quot; 
    /targetplatform:&quot;v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\
    Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\
    .NETFramework\v4.0&quot; /allowDup /out:@(MainAssembly) 
    &quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(AssembliesToMerge-&gt;'&quot;% 
  (FullPath)&quot;', ' ')"/>
  </Target>
```

When I pipe the output of msbuild into a text file I get:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.57.0
 Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 19/05/2015 11:22:16.Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\CompanyName.csproj" 
on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\
CompanyName.csproj" (1) is building "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web
\CompanyName.Core.Web.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\
CompanyName.Core.Web.csproj" (2) is building "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks
\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
    GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" 
because all output files are up-to-date with respect
 to the input files.
    CoreCompile:
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.dll
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.csproj" (default targets).
    Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\CompanyName.Core.Web.csproj" (2) is building "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\CompanyName.Core.csproj" (4) on node 1 (default targets).
    Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\CompanyName.Core.csproj" (4) is building "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\CompanyName.DataAccess.csproj" (5) on node 1 (default targets).
    Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\CompanyName.DataAccess.csproj" (5) is building "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\CompanyName.Models.csproj" (6) on node 1 (default targets).
    Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\CompanyName.Models.csproj" (6) is building "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\CompanyName.Utilities.csproj" (7) on node 1 (default targets).
    GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CoreCompile:
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      CompanyName.Utilities -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Utilities.dll
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\CompanyName.Utilities.csproj" (default targets).
    GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CoreCompile:
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      CompanyName.Models -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Models.dll
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\CompanyName.Models.csproj" (default targets).
    GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CoreCompile:
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      CompanyName.DataAccess -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\bin\Debug\CompanyName.DataAccess.dll
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\CompanyName.DataAccess.csproj" (default targets).
    GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CoreCompile:
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      CompanyName.Core -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.dll
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\CompanyName.Core.csproj" (default targets).
    GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CoreCompile:
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      CompanyName.Core.Web -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.Web.dll
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\CompanyName.Core.Web.csproj" (default targets).
    Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\CompanyName.csproj" (1) is building "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\CompanyName.Logging.csproj" (8) on node 1 (default targets).
    CoreCompile:
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      CompanyName.Logging -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Logging.dll
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\CompanyName.Logging.csproj" (default targets).
    GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    CoreCompile:
      C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva- /reference:C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.dll /reference:C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.dll /reference:C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.Web.dll /reference:C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\bin\Debug\CompanyName.DataAccess.dll /reference:C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Logging.dll /reference:C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Models.dll /reference:C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Utilities.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /debug+ /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\CompanyName.dll /target:library /utf8output Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\sthompson\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
    CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
      Copying file from "obj\Debug\CompanyName.dll" to "bin\Debug\CompanyName.dll".
      CompanyName -> C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\bin\Debug\CompanyName.dll
      Copying file from "obj\Debug\CompanyName.pdb" to "bin\Debug\CompanyName.pdb".
    AfterBuild:
      ====================================================================================================================================
      MERGING: CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks;CompanyName.Core;CompanyName.Core.Web;CompanyName.DataAccess;CompanyName.Logging;CompanyName.Models;CompanyName.Utilities
      ====================================================================================================================================
      "..\..\..\Libraries\dependencies\ILMerge\Ilmerge.exe" /internalize:"ILMerge-internalize-excludes.txt" /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /allowDup /out:bin\Debug\CompanyName.dll "obj\Debug\CompanyName.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.Web.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\bin\Debug\CompanyName.DataAccess.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Logging.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Models.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Utilities.dll"
      The system cannot find the path specified.
    C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\CompanyName.csproj(75,5): error MSB3073: The command ""..\..\..\Libraries\dependencies\ILMerge\Ilmerge.exe" /internalize:"ILMerge-internalize-excludes.txt" /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /allowDup /out:bin\Debug\CompanyName.dll "obj\Debug\CompanyName.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.Web.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\bin\Debug\CompanyName.DataAccess.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Logging.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Models.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Utilities.dll"" exited with code 3.
    Done Building Project "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\CompanyName.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\CompanyName.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (AfterBuild target) -> 
      C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName\CompanyName.csproj(75,5): error MSB3073: The command ""..\..\..\Libraries\dependencies\ILMerge\Ilmerge.exe" /internalize:"ILMerge-internalize-excludes.txt" /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /allowDup /out:bin\Debug\CompanyName.dll "obj\Debug\CompanyName.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.Web.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\bin\Debug\CompanyName.DataAccess.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Logging.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Models.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\bin\Debug\CompanyName.Utilities.dll"" exited with code 3.

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.78
```

However, the line below which is causing the error, when run manually through Command Prompt executes as expected.

```
 "..\..\..\Libraries\dependencies\ILMerge\Ilmerge.exe"
     /internalize:"ILMerge-internalize-excludes.txt" 
    /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)
    \Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\
    .NETFramework\v4.0" /allowDup /out:bin\Debug\CompanyName.dll 
    "obj\Debug\CompanyName.dll" 
    "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\
    CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks\bin\Debug\
    CompanyName.Core.ApplicationBlocks.dll" 
"C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core\
bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Core.Web\
bin\Debug\CompanyName.Core.Web.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.DataAccess\
bin\Debug\CompanyName.DataAccess.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Logging\
bin\Debug\CompanyName.Logging.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Models\
bin\Debug\CompanyName.Models.dll" "C:\CWHG\Magnus\Source\Core\CompanyName.Utilities\
bin\Debug\CompanyName.Utilities.dll"
```

It might be worth noting that I also get the same error when building normally in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: And you have ilmerge in the folder downloaded to your local workspace?

Comment: Yes, it must be something with my machine as the other developers on my team, when on the same version of the code, can build successfully.  ILMerge.exe is in the repo so it's not that.  When I paste in the last "code block" above into Command Prompt, opened at the folder in which the `.csproj` file resides, it executes successfully showing that all the files do actually exist.

Comment: What if you based the path in something like $(SolutionDir) just to make sure that your relative path is relative to what you are expecting.

Comment: Yeah, everything is correct - as I said before if I open a Command Prompt window myself (at the same location) and run the command that is generated in the AfterBuild event it works as expected, it's only not working when run via msbuild.  Running via msbuild works for every other developer in my team (with the exact same setup).